# Is it possible to get the field name and turn it to string so that I can store the string to another field?

Tags: php, mysql

Im currently working on a career test project and I have columns like ABM, TVL, STEM, etc., in which the scores (for each category) of the users (who took the test) are stored accordingly. These field names are also the category names. I also included a CareerResult column where the category name with the highest score must be stored.

For example, if the user has scores for

ABM - 1 
TVL - 2 
STEM - 3

In the CareerResult column, the word "STEM" shall be stored since the user got the highest score in this catergory.

Is this possible? If yes, what query shall I use?

Comment: The table `information_schema.COLUMNS` can give you the name of a column in a result set of a query.

Comment: @Martin nope, my question is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional logic:

```
select . . .,
       (case when stem = greatest(abm, tlv, stem) then 'stem'
             when tlv = greatest(abm, tlv, stem) then 'tlv'
             when abm = greatest(abm, tlv, stem) then 'abm'
        end) as column_with_max
. . .
```

Note that in the case of ties, you this returns only the first value encountered.

This could also be popularly written as a simple case:

```
select . . .,
       (case greatest(abm, tlv, stem)
             when stem then 'stem'
             when tlv then 'tlv'
             when abm then 'abm'
        end) as column_with_max
```

Note that both methods assume that the columns are no `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you so much!